# How to use a struct with a library in a tableview

Tags: ios, struct, tableview

I have created a struct with a library and have initialised that struct in another struct. Now I want to use the resulting struct in a Table View. However, the struct currently doesn't work properly. I've tried to find out why, but seem to be stuck.

It looks like the issue is that the library doesn't get translated properly to the struct. For in instance, when I do a count on an instance of the struct, using the following code:

```
var personalDetailsStructExtra: [PersonalDetailsStruct] = []
personalDetailsStructExtra.count
```

It returns 0, while it should be 5 (See code below, there are 5 entries into the dictionary):

```
struct PersonalDetailsStructLibrary {

let library = [
[
"title": "Country",
"icon": "country.pdf",
"questions": ["Belgium", "France", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Sweden", "UK", "USA"]
],
[
"title": "Age",
"icon": "age.pdf",
"questions": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
],
[
"title": "Gender",
"icon": "gender.pdf",
"questions": ["Male", "Female", "Other"]
],
[
"title": "Height",
"icon": "height.pdf",
"questions": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
],
[
"title": "Weight",
"icon": "weight.pdf",
"questions": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
],
]    }
```

And

```
struct PersonalDetailsStruct {
var title: String?
var icon: UIImage?
var questions: [String] = []

init(index: Int) {
    let personalDetailsStructLibrary = PersonalDetailsStructLibrary().library
    let personalDetailsDictionary = personalDetailsStructLibrary[index]

    title = personalDetailsDictionary["title"] as! String!

    let iconNamePD = personalDetailsDictionary["icon"] as! String!
    icon = UIImage(named: iconNamePD!)

    questions += personalDetailsDictionary["artists"] as! [String]
}    }
```

As you can see in the code I want use the struct to fill up a label (title), image (icon) and UITextView with UIPickerView (questions) in my table view.

Since it doesn't work, I'm looking for either:

A: Feedback on how to make this code work in a tableview

B: Whether I should use another method to populate the dynamic cells in my tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the `personalDetailsStructExtra` array, only then you would see the required count.

```
var personalDetailsStructExtra = [PersonalDetailsStruct]()

PersonalDetailsStructLibrary().library.count
let count = PersonalDetailsStructLibrary().library.count
for i in 0..<count {
    personalDetailsStructExtra.append(PersonalDetailsStruct(index: i))
}

personalDetailsStructExtra.count  // 5
```

A better option is to use the Library struct to construct and maintain all model objects.

```
struct PersonalDetailDataSource {

    let library = [
        [
            "title": "Country",
            "icon": "country.pdf",
            "questions": ["Belgium", "France", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Sweden", "UK", "USA"]
        ],
        [
            "title": "Age",
            "icon": "age.pdf",
            "questions": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
        ],
        [
            "title": "Gender",
            "icon": "gender.pdf",
            "questions": ["Male", "Female", "Other"]
        ],
        [
            "title": "Height",
            "icon": "height.pdf",
            "questions": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
        ],
        [
            "title": "Weight",
            "icon": "weight.pdf",
            "questions": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
        ],
    ]

    var personalDetails = [PersonalDetail]()

    init() {
        loadData()
    }

    mutating private func loadData() {
        for i in 0..<library.count {

            let personalDetailsDictionary = library[i]
            let title = personalDetailsDictionary["title"] as! String!
            let iconName = personalDetailsDictionary["icon"] as! String!
            let questions = personalDetailsDictionary["questions"] as! [String]

            personalDetails.append(PersonalDetail(title: title, iconName: iconName, questions: questions))
        }
    }
}

struct PersonalDetail {
    var title: String?
    var icon: UIImage?
    var questions: [String] = []

    init(title: String, iconName: String, questions: [String]) {
        self.title = title
        if let icon = UIImage(named: iconName) {
            self.icon = icon
        }
        self.questions = questions
    }
}


PersonalDetailDataSource().personalDetails.count  // count: 5
```